# C# How can i use Entity Framework Entities with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6

when i tried that

```
using (var db = new NewDbContext())
{
    var AllItems = new ObservableCollection<db.Items>();
    ItemsDataGrid.ItemsSource = AllItems;
}
```

i got that error

> 'db' is a variable but is used like a type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `db.Items` is not a Type but a collection of a certain type (I suppose that type is `Item`?) .

So try this:

```
    var AllItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>(db.Items);
    ItemsDataGrid.ItemsSource = AllItems;
```

Answer (score 1):

`db.Items` will return a collection of type `IQueryable<Item>`. It looks like you want to convert the result of `IQueryable<T>` to `ObservableCollection<T>`.

You actually need to pass the `Items` in the constructor of `Observable`. The correct code would be :

```
ObservableCollection<Item> AllItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>(db.Items);
```

and then:

```
ItemsDataGrid.ItemsSource = AllItems;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, but i can't use the ObservableCollection like that
"Using the generic type 'ObservableCollection<T>' requires 1 type argument"

Comment: @ahmedpio have you specified the generic type parameter `Item` there ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this issue. You can also directly use:

```
ObservableCollection<Item> AllItems = db.Items.Local;
```

To populate the collection you might need to call `db.Items.Load()`, which is an extension from `System.Data.Entity`